# EditText not accepting Text when i use my Samsung Note as the emulator

Tags: java, android

When I use the emulator my Edittext part runs fine and doesnt force my app to stop. Now when i switch to my Samsung Mobile phone it forces the app to close.

This is the methods I have tried. Its working fine in my emulator but in my samsung not working.

```
public void onClickAnswerField(View view){
        ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.answerField)).getText().toString();

    }
```